# definition of the space of functions $L^\infty_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n) $?

Tags: functional-analysis

I couldn't find it on Google. I know that $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ is the space of locally integrable functions, but what about $L^\infty_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n) $?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $f \in L^{\infty}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if, for every compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $f \in L^{\infty}(K)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $f\in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if for every compact $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $f\chi_K\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $\chi_K$ denotes the indicator function of $K$.

Comment: Thank you very much icurays1!

Comment: Note the minor edit - $f\vert_K$ didn't quite make sense in this context.